# The Gradle failure AndroidX incompatibilities in this Flutter app

Tags: android, gradle, flutter, androidx

I get this error when I try to run my flutter app on an android emulator, I use a MacBook and VSCode, The app runs fine on the ios simulator.

```
*** What went wrong:                                                      
Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugBuild'.                         
> Android dependency 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0' is set to compileOnly/provided which is not supported**

**These are my build.gradle dependcies:**



 dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
    }
```

**and inside of gradle.properties this is all i have:**

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

**in my app level build.gradle :**

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.androidx.support.test:runner:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.androidx.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0'
}
```

Comment: can you provide complete stack trace of the exception?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a version conflict. It might get solved just by changing your gradle and kotlin version as follow.

```
// change kotlin_version above 1.3.0 like 1.3.31
// change build gradle version from 3.2.1 to 3.3.2
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.31"
```

I think this might help you.